# From dictionary of dictionaries to pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the below response:

```
response_json = {'insights': {'data': [{'name': 'page_fans', 'period': 'day', 'values': [{'value': 2123, 'end_time': '2021-09-13T07:00:00+0000'}, {'value': 94286, 'end_time': '2021-09-14T07:00:00+0000'}], 'title': 'Lifetime Total Likes', 'description': 'Lifetime: The total number', 'id': '247/insights/page_fans/day'}, {'name': 'page_fans_city', 'period': 'day', 'values': [{'value': {'Rio de Janeiro, RJ, Brazil': 233, 'Perth, WA, Australia': 236, 'Querétaro, Querétaro Arteaga, Mexico': 248}, 'end_time': '2021-09-14T07:00:00+0000'}], 'title': 'Lifetime Likes', 'id': '247/insights/page_fans_city/day'},{'name': 'page_fan_adds_unique', 'period': 'day', 'values': [{'value': 5, 'end_time': '2021-09-13T07:00:00+0000'}, {'value': 4, 'end_time': '2021-09-14T07:00:00+0000'}], 'title': 'Daily New Likes', 'description': 'Daily: The number of new people who have liked your Page (Unique Users)', 'id': '247/insights/page_fan_adds_unique/day'},{'name': 'page_fans_by_unlike_source_unique', 'period': 'day', 'values': [{'value': {'Deactivated or Memorialized Account Removals': 4, 'Unlikes from Page, Posts, or News Feed': 1}, 'end_time': '2021-09-13T07:00:00+0000'}, {'value': {'Deactivated or Memorialized Account Removals': 7, 'Unlikes from Page, Posts, or News Feed': 1}, 'end_time': '2021-09-14T07:00:00+0000'}], 'title': 'Daily Unlike Sources', 'description': 'Daily: The number of people', 'id': '2474/insights/page_fans_by_unlike_source_unique/day'}], 'paging': {'previous': 'https://graph.1', 'next': 'https://graph.2'}}, 'id': '247'}
```

that I'm trying to have look like this, where in the dictionary each '`name`' key is a column, and each `name` key has the value `values` in their respective row. And the ID is the last key/value pair in this case 247

| page_fans | page_fans_city | page_fans_by_unlike_source_unique | id | asof_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2123 | [{'value': {'Rio de Janeiro, RJ, Brazil': 233, 'Perth, WA, Australia': 236, 'Querétaro, Querétaro Arteaga, Mexico': 248}] | {'Deactivated or Memorialized Account Removals': 4, 'Unlikes from Page, Posts, or News Feed': 1} | 247 | 2021-09-19 1122 |

This is what I've tried so far, but I'm having issues placing everything together:

```
import pandas as pd

import requests
import re
from datetime import datetime

asof_date = datetime.now()
    
pat_id = r'(\d+)'

df_list = []
while True:
    try:
        for rdata in response_json['insights']['data']:

            df = pd.DataFrame(rdata['values'])

            id_val = re.search(pat_id, rdata['id'])
            col_name = rdata['name']

            df['id'] = id_val.group(0) if id_val else None

            df['asof_date'] = pd.to_datetime(asof_date, format='%Y-%m-%d-%H%M')
            df_transformed = df.rename(columns={df.columns[0]: col_name})

            df_list += [df_transformed]

        response = requests.get(response_json['paging']['next'])
        response_json = response.json()
    except KeyError:
        break
```

Comment: you want your dataframe to have dicts?

Comment: @sammywemmy oh actually, scratch my previous statement. yes the row can have a dictionary

Comment: please give an example of expected result

Comment: @TomerS the table I posted is the example I'm looking to see